# Where should I install Xubuntu to boot on grub?

Tags: grub2, system-installation, xubuntu, gparted

Last time I lost my grub and Xubuntu after having update Win7 to win10.
So, to be sure where should I install xubuntu to boot with grub menu and select xubuntu or win10. Or ,maybe , I have to change all  the partitions layout ?

[Gparted Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVybM.png)

Answer (score 0):

A Windows installation kills the bootloader. At least. You will have to boot with a live system (CD, USB) and repair your grub bootloader. How to do this, depends on a few factors. But it is not very complicated.

You could use a second hdd drive for xubuntu and just plug it off during Windows installations. When the installation is done, boot plug on the xubuntu disk, boot and update grub to reflect the changes.

Comment: After I lost the grub and xubuntu , I couldn't repair grub bootloader with boot-repair...                                                                                                                                I  don't understand your second part , actually win10 is installed I think on sda1 sda2 sda3 . Before that  I had tried to recover my grub with "parted" and mount a partition ( /dev/sda6), so now this one is useless for me ... I have a question usually where the grub is placed in my screen to boot grub ?